# How to get Custom Metrics from Azure app-insight in Prometheus server?

Tags: azure, prometheus, azure-application-insights, prometheus-alertmanager, appinsights

Because set alert rule in Azure is too expensive, I want set alert rule in Prometheus instead.
However, is there any way to expose the metrics on Azure(app insight) to Prometheus server?

(I already have some application running on Azure now and have some metrics on app-insight, but don't know how to get these metrics in Prometheus server.)

Comment: Is https://promitor.io/ something that can help?